Adding two-way fixed effects for zero inflated Poisson model
I am working with a zero inflated Poisson model. I am using the glmmTMB
My outcome variable is the number of burglaries in all of Texas between 2000 and 2015. My unit of analysis are counties (county). My main variable of interest is male unemployment rate
Here is my baseline model
z1 <- glmmTMB(burglaries ~ male.unemployment + growth + gun.ownership + temperature 
+ offset(log(county.pop)), data = texas.data, 
family = poisson, ziformula=~1)

This works fine. I want to add year (year) and county (county) fixed effects to this model. Below is my best. I am pretty sure that my notation is off and that I am just adding random effects (the summary output says so). What would the correct notation be?
z1 <- glmmTMB(burglaries ~ male.unemployment + growth + gun.ownership + temperature 
+ offset(log(county.pop)) + (1|id+year), data = texas.data,
 family = poisson, ziformula=~1)

Thank you!

You're right, + (1|id+year) adds a random effect. Why not only add + id + year?

There are 254 counties in Texas. Are you really sure you want to add it as a fixed effect?

@rosapluesch you mean like this: z1 <- glmmTMB(burglaries ~ male.unemployment + growth + gun.ownership + temperature

offset(log(county.pop)) + as.factor(id) + as.factor(year), data = texas.data,
family = poisson, ziformula=~1)


@YouLocalRUser yes, that's how you add fixed effects, independently of the questions if it makes sense to add those variables as fixed effects as Edward mentioned
